# Are there a C# equivalents of Python's iter() and next() functions?

Tags: python, c#, iterator, ienumerator

Python's [`iter(.)`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) and [`next(.)`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#next) built-in functions allow iterating a list (or other objects that implement `__iter__(self)` and `__next__(self)`) without a for loop and without an index.

Does C# have something equivalent to `iter(.)` and `next(.)`? The

---

Say that for some reason you wanted to merge two lists sorted numbers without using for loops nor indices. You could do so using iterators and `next(.)` as follows:

```py
def merge(nums1, nums2):
    nums1Iter = iter(nums1)
    nums2Iter = iter(nums2)
    num1 = next(nums1Iter)
    num2 = next(nums2Iter)
    while True:
      if num1 <= num2:
        yield num1
        try:
          num1 = next(nums1Iter)
        except StopIteration:
          yield num2
          yield from nums2Iter
          break
      else:
        yield num2
        try:
          num2 = next(nums2Iter)
        except StopIteration:
          yield num1
          yield from nums1Iter
          break

nums1 = range(0, 10, 2)
nums2 = range(1, 20, 3)
print(list(merge(nums1, nums2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C# calls them **Enumerators**. The [`IEnumerator Interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) and [`IEnumerator<T> Interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1) each have a `MoveNext` method a `Current` property which you can use to iterate without for loops nor indices as follows:

```
int[] numsArr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
IEnumerator numsEnumerator = numsArr.GetEnumerator();
int num;
while (numsEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
  num = (int) numsEnumerator.Current;
}
```

would print out:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Notes:

- Arrays, Lists, and other classes each have a `GetEnumerator` method which you can use to get an Enumerator of the Array, List, etc. object.
- `IEnumerator.Current` is of type `object` so you have to do an explicit cast if assigning its value to a typed variable (not sure if *typed variable* is the appropriate terminology here). Otherwise, you'll get a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to ...` error.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, there isn't a direct equivalent to Python's iter() and next() functions because C# and Python have different approaches to iteration. However, you can achieve similar functionality using interfaces and classes.

In C#, you typically use ***IEnumerable*** and ***IEnumerator*** interfaces for iteration. Here's an example that demonstrates a simple iterator in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class MyIterator : IEnumerable
{
    private int[] data;

    public MyIterator(int[] values)
    {
        data = values;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Iterator(this);
    }

    private class Iterator : IEnumerator
    {
        private MyIterator collection;
        private int currentIndex = -1;

        public Iterator(MyIterator collection)
        {
            this.collection = collection;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (currentIndex == -1 || currentIndex >= collection.data.Length)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                return collection.data[currentIndex];
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            currentIndex++;
            return currentIndex < collection.data.Length;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            currentIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        MyIterator myIterator = new MyIterator(values);

        foreach (var value in myIterator)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, **MyIterator** implements the **IEnumerable** interface, and it has an inner class **Iterator** that implements the **IEnumerator** interface. The **GetEnumerator** method returns an instance of the **Iterator** class, which allows you to iterate over the elements in the **MyIterator** class using a *foreach* loop.

This is a simplified example, and in a real-world scenario, you might use generics and other features to make the iterator more flexible and reusable.

Comment: Thanks for the example! Just a quick note that `MyIetarator.data` is a C# Array and since C# Arrays implement IEnumerable, Arrays already have a `GetEnumerator` method, so I think `MyIterator.GetEnumerator` could work just as well by returning `this.data.GetEnumerator;` instead of `new Iterator(this);`. In the case that `data` had been of some other class that does not implement `IEnumerable`, then I see that value of implementing your own custom class (`Iterator`) that implements `IEnumerator` and then returning an instance of `Iterator` from `MyIterator.GetEnumerator`.